# При отправке формы данные не сохраняются и экшн show выводит пустой шаблон

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Проблема кажется детской, но все же серфинг по инету не принес результатов. Да и сами Рельсы только начинаю изучать, поэтому буду очень признателен за подсказку: что делать, как делать.

Итак, контроллер и экшны, вроде все выглядит нормально:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # /items/1 GET
  def show
    unless @item = Item.where(id: params[:id]).first
      render plain: "Page not found", status: 404
    end
  end

  # /items/new GET
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  # /items/1/edit GET
  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  # /items POST
  def create
    @item = Item.create(item_params)
     if @item.errors.empty?
       redirect_to item_path(@item)
     else
       render "new"
     end
  end

  # /items/1 PUT
  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.update_attributes(item_params)
    if @item.errors.empty?
      redirect_to item_path(@item)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

# /items/1 DELETE
  def destroy
  end


  private
   def item_params
     params.require(:item).permit(:price, :name, :weight, :description)
   end
end
```

Файл routes.rb:

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     resources :items
   end
```

Модель:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :price, :name, :real, :weight, :description
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0, allow_nil: true}
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Вьюха new.html.erb, где и создаем новый товар, но он не сохраняется:

```
<h1>Create new item</h1>

<%= form_for @item, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <br>Price: </br> <%=  f.text_field :price %></p>
  <p>Name:</br>  <%=  f.text_field :name %></p>
  <p>Description:</br>  <%=  f.text_field :description %></p>
  <p>Weight: </br> <%=  f.text_field :weight %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Create the stuff" %></p>
<%end%>
```

Товар должен отображаться в show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @item.name %></h1>

<ul>
  <li>Price: <%= @item.price %>$</li>
  <li>Name: <%= @item.name %>$</li>
  <li>Description: <%= @item.description %></li>
  <li>Weight: <%= @item.weight %>kg</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Вводим данные]

[image: Но получаем пустой шаблон без них]

Ввожу данные в форме, все ок, но выводит пустой шаблоню

Буду очень благодарен помощь! Уже не знаю где искать решение, и не понимаю, в чём загвоздка =(

Comment: `attr_accessor :price, :name, :real, :weight, :description`? Зачем это?

Comment: А что  у вас в логах? Если итем не сохраняется, то на show страничку какого итема вы переходите?

Comment: все заработало после закоментирования рядка 
attr_accessor :price, :name, :real, :weight, :description .....что странно

Comment: Буду делать дальше, надеюсь эта проблема больше не вылезет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Беда в том, что вы зачем-то переопределили методы чтения и записи атрибутов*: `price`/`price=`, `name`/`name=`, и т. д.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :price, :name, :real, :weight, :description
```

- Вы косвенно унаследовали `Item` от `ActiveRecord::Base`. ActiveRecord сам при начале использования выяснит, какие у модели есть поля, пользуясь соответствующей таблицей в БД. Соответствующие столбцам методы он добавит сам.
- `attr_accessor :foo` можно считать эквивалентом:

  ```
  def foo
    @foo
  end

  def foo=(value)
    @foo = value
  end
  ```

  ...и он **замещает созданные AR методы** для атрибута `foo`, если он есть в БД. В общем случае, полученные таким образом атрибуты сохраняются только в одноимённых полях (instance variables) самого объекта. AR никак об этих значениях не узнаёт, и потому сохранить их не может.

Убрав `attr_accessor`, вы начали пользоваться атрибутами, определяемыми самим AR. Разумеется, значения присваемые *в них* AR уже *обнаруживает* и *сохраняет*.

---

* Под "атрибутом" в Ruby обычно понимают пару методов для чтения и записи под определённым именем внутри объекта некоего значения. Скажем, "атрибут `foo`" это пара методов: `foo` и `foo=(value)`. Характерны только названия и число аргументов, реализации же могут быть любыми, они необязательно должны совпадать с тем, что выдаёт `attr_accessor`; тот же AR использует собственные.

Answer (score 1):

все заработало после закоментирования рядка `аttr_accessor :price, :name, :real, :weight, :description` .....что странно

Comment: Это не странно, это правильно. Зачем он там вообще был, моделька сама всё умеет. Кстати, поправьте в show поиск сущности, в edit у вас же нормально через find прописано.